# Configuring Juniper switch with python(paramiko)

Tags: python, paramiko, juniper

I am trying to push config into multiple juniper devices. But as a test I enter into config mode and change config.

```
client1 = paramiko.SSHClient()

client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client1.connect(IP, username=username, password=password)

configure = client1.invoke_shell()

configure.send('configure')

configure.send('set interfaces ge-0/0/10 description "test"')

configure.send('show | compare')

print configure.recv(1000)

client1.close()
```

I am expecting the output as below:

```
[edit interfaces ge-0/0/10]
-   description "Internet Simulation Interface connect to QFX ge-0/0/21";
+   description test;
```

But the actual output is this:

`JUNOS 12.3X50-D35 built 2013-10-22 07:02:18 UTC`

---

Comment: For the above query the answer import "SSHClientInteraction" from paramiko_expect. But now the issue is able to get into config mode but unable to send further commands

Comment: This is the new code 

*********************
client1 = paramiko.SSHClient()
client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client1.connect(IP, username=username, password=password)
interact = SSHClientInteraction(client1, timeout=10, display=True)
#interact.expect ('sivabalask@in.ibm.com@usrdrsf072ccpf0>')
interact.send('configure')
interact.expect (
interact.send('show | compare')
cmd_output = interact.current_output_clean
print cmd_output
client1.close()
**************
There is something else missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the first lines of the `Juniper CLI`, try coding a higher receiving bytes in :

```
print configure.recv(1000)
```

Try:

```
print configure.recv(4096)
```

Let me know.

Comment: Well, I tried the max receive count 65535 still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using the Junos Eznc, library from juniper for junos devices. [Junos-Eznc GitHub](https://github.com/Juniper/py-junos-eznc)

Comment: To use Junos pyez in need to have netconf enabled in all juniper devices.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below mentioned snippet? Sometimes, you have the wait for few seconds to receive some bytes on your stdin.

```
configure.send('show | compare')

time.sleep(2)

print configure.recv(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the'cli'before sending commands?

```
configure = client1.invoke_shell ()
configure.send ('cli') <--- Add
configure.send ('configure')
```

You are in shell mode a first when you connect to JUNOS by SSH..So you can move to operation mode by using `cli`.

```sh
(lab-network) bash-3.2$ ssh root@localhost -p 2201 
Password:
--- JUNOS 12.1X47-D15.4 built 2014-11-12 02:13:59 UTC
root@vsrx1% cli
root@vsrx1> configure 
Entering configuration mode

[edit]
root@vsrx1#
```